# Webstorm 8.0.3 jQuery inspections

Tags: jquery, webstorm

Whenever i write down a piece of jQuery inside Webstorm 8.0.3 it gives me these sort of warnings:

> Unresolved method or function `$()`

I already imported the jQuery library in my project settings by going to:

> Settings -> Project settings -> JavaScript -> Libraries

And clicking the **Add** button, and after that specify a path to the jQuery library and click the **Apply** button.

The screen looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this or is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to [this site](http://jquery.com/download/) and download the uncompressed version of jQuery
   2.1.1. (Or any other version, as long its not compressed)
2. Go to your settings by pressing
   <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
3. Navigate to the header

   > Project settings

   And navigate to this tab

   > JavaScript -> Libraries
4. Click the <kbd>Add...</kbd> button and specify the path to the
   jQuery file, set the Framework type to jQuery. Also fill in the rest
   of the info, it should look like this now:

   [image]
5. Press the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.
6. Press the <kbd>Manage Scopes...</kbd> button and on the right side of the window where it says **Libraries**. Click it where your project is and select the jQuery plugin you just added. Now it should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

known issue, see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10908
See http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5510988#5510988 for possible workaround